# error in reflection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, reflection

Actually , what i want to invoke is a service method, so some people are saying that with regular reflection , how can one load autowired elements? I am new to spring framework. I am working on web application designed using Spring-hibernate framework.
So in one case i saved class name and method name in DB. And now i want to invoke method via reflection:

```
 Class cls = Class.forName("com.xyz.pqr.Invest");


    Object obj = cls.newInstance();

    //call the printIt method
    Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("exec", noparams);
    method.invoke(obj, null);
```

by fetching class name and method name from DB. But its not fulfilling my purpose. Kindly tell how to invoke method via reflection using spring . I googled it out and something like to implement ApplicationContextAware i found. But not clear idea.
Actually , what i want to invoke is a service method, so some people are saying that with regular reflection , how can one load autowired elements? 
Invest is a service class , in that we have api exec to process some data

```
public void exex(int a, int b, String c){**}
```

thanks

Comment: It's nothing to with spring, you should dig into java reflection instead. Check first your invoked class is accessible from callee.

Comment: Actually , what i want to invoke is a service method, so some people are saying that with regular reflection , how can one load autowired elements?

Comment: Is the method accessible? What is the signature of the `exec` method? What is the `Invest` class? The information you provided is very insufficient for us to help. You may want to add more info

Comment: I think that won't work, because spring uses proxies for beans.

Comment: Invest is a service class , in that we have api exec to process some data

    public void exex(int a, int b, String c){**}

Answer (score 6):

What you need to do is make your caller `ApplicationContextAware` and use the `getBean()` method to get the instance of the `Invest` class instead of `cls.newInstance()`.

Something like below;

```
public TheCaller implements org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware {
    /** The spring application context */
    @Autowired
    private org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext springContext;

    public void callService(String serviceName, String theClass, String methodName) {
       Class cls = Class.forName(theClass);
       Object obj = applicationContext.getBean(serviceName); // Or use applicationContext.getBeansOfType(cls)
       Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, noparams);
       method.invoke(obj, null);
    }    

}
```

The **serviceName** is the name of the bean configured in spring.